# Oracle Database 19c no listener

Tags: oracle, service, oracle-sqldeveloper

I installed  Oracle Database 19c and was able to connect to the database using sqlplus in command line. However when I try to use SQL developer I'm unable to connect. I noticed I don't have any listener service like I did when I had Oracle Database 21c installed on another computer. Is this why I can't access it on SQL developer? And if so how do I create that listener?

Access the database through SQL Developer.

Comment: This is definitely why you're not connecting. The listener is typically installed at the same time as the database. You can use the Network Manager utility to configure one if it isn't already done. Perhaps check the listener config files in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin first; if listener.ora is already there, see if the lsnrctl utility can start it.

Comment: I would assume but there no network manager utility program installed either and trying to start with lsnrctl doesn't work either.

Comment: are you getting a specific error when starting the listener? Please add the commands attempted and the output to your question.

Comment: I was using lsnrctl start which was giving me error but ofc after one night of sleep it magically works without me doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have the reputation to comment, so I'm posting this here.)

Just wanted to say that I just encountered the same issue.

1. I installed Oracle 19c on Windows as "Software Only".
2. I used `dbca.bat` to create a database with a single pluggable database through the "basic" configuration. In the past I've gone through the "advanced" configuration, and I'm wondering if that's what lead to this.

So now I'm dropping the database and will try re-creating it to see if using the advanced DB installation provides a listener.

**Edit**

After deleting the database, then going back through the DB installation in `dbca.bat` via the "advanced" installation option, I noticed that the listener configuration was actually disabled by default, and I had to choose to add a listener.